# Why is IntelliJ's inspector highlighting this code?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-inspection

IntelliJ seems to think that there is a potential bug with my code, and I can't quite see why. This has to do with the `Nonnull` annotations; I am telling IntelliJ that some fields cannot be null, and I am ensuring that they never are allowed to become null, but IntelliJ doesn't like it, all the same.

Here is an example of the code in question.

```
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;

public class Something {
     static final Long DEFAULT_ID = -1L;

     @Nonnull
     public Long id;

     public Something() {
         id = DEFAULT_ID;
     }

     @Nonnull
     public Long getId() {
         return this.id;
     }

     public Something setId(Long id) {
         this.id = id != null ? id : DEFAULT_ID;
         return this;
     }
}
```

When I do this, IntelliJ's inspector produces a warning on the `id` parameter of the `setId(Long)` method prototype, warning me that the class field for `id` is annotated with `Nonnull`. This is in spite of me manually checking for null in the body of the method & handling it if need be. `Something#id` will never become null via this method.

However, if I change the method to be like this, the inspection warning goes away entirely:

```
public Something setId(Long id) {
    if (id != null) 
        this.id = id;
    else 
        this.id = DEFAULT_ID; 
    return this;
}
```

In theory, both implementations are effectively the same; in fact, IntelliJ recommends using the ternary operator when I go with the if-else approach, for stylistic purposes. Why would IntelliJ produce a warning on the first implementation--using the ternary operator--but not the second? Is this just an oversight in the code inspector, or am I missing something important here? The warning can be suppressed by suppressing "NullableProblems", but I want to make sure that there isn't something wrong with using the ternary operator here. Any advice?

Comment: I'm actually not seeing any warning for the first one.  Then again, I'm being notified that `org.jetbrains.NotNull` would be used in lieu of `@Nonnull`.

Comment: @Makoto You bring up a good point; I configured my IDE to use the javax annotation instead some time ago. I will have to try with that setting reverted and see if the JetBrains-brand annotation behaves any differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug.

I create an issue in JetBrains tracker for you.

Vote/comment here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-178172